# What are the factors to bear in mind when choosing framework?

Tags: frameworks

I am currently trying to make use of a object recognition project named [object recognition kitchen](http://ecto.willowgarage.com/recognition/). This project is built on top of [ecto](http://ecto.willowgarage.com/index.html) which is a lightweight hybrid C++/Python framework for organizing computations as directed acyclic graphs.

I don't have any experience of developing projects on top of frameworks(I also don't know how to efficiently find useful frameworks). And I am wondering what is the main concerns to bear in mind when choosing the framework for projects.

There's [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848288/choosing-the-correct-framework),but my confusion is not solved by the answers.

Any comments or thoughts are welcomed.Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm a php web developer and when I was looking for some fw to work with and thus make easy me working I always looked for this.

1. Easy to learn.
2. Full docs and tutorials.
3. Great community either in its forums or elsewhere.
4. free. XD. many people use free stuff around the world. so there are many people who can help you.

3rd and 4th points can be summarized as very popular.

And the most important: make test about how easy could be develop some task in each of your chosen fw.

Hope this could help you.